# How to add a column in QGIS via Python

Tags: qgis, python

I have a point shapefile and a polygon shapefile in QGIS.  Now I want to use the point shapefile's value add to polygon shapefile (be a column in the end).

There are colors with each value, and make the color overlay on the polygon.

How to do it with Python??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Python, you don't need QGIS, except if you want to create a plugin. 
In this case, you should consider PyQGIS with the reference given by Curlew

But you can also use Python modules like [pyshp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.1.4), [osgeo (gdal and ogr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.9.1)) or [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/0.10) and [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2.17) without QGIS

In both cases, you need a join field that will link the polygon shapefile to the point shapefile.

**Example with Fiona and Shapely** (all the elements of a shapefile (schema,geometry, records) are processed using Python dictionaries).

With ogr and Fiona it is easier to create a new shapefile, copying the original shapefile (geometry and attributes), and adding new fields with the desired values than modify the original shapefile.

```py
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import fiona
# open the polygon shapefile
with fiona.collection('polygon.shp', 'r') as polygon:
    # copy of the schema of the original polygon shapefile to the output shapefile (copy)
    schema = polygon.schema.copy()
    # creation of the new field color in the new schema
    schema['properties']['color'] = 'str' 
        # output shapefile with the new schema
        with fiona.collection('join_poly_pt.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
            # open the point shapefile with colors
            with fiona.collection('point.shp', 'r') as points:
                 polygons = [elem for elem in polygon]
                 points = [elem for elem in point]
                 # joint
                 for poly in polygons:
                     for pt in points:
                         # common field for the join
                         if poly['properties']['test'] == pt['properties']['test']:
                             # construction of the new shapefile
                             res = {}                  
                             res['properties'] = poly['properties'] 
                             res['properties']['color'] = pt['properties']['color'] 
                             # geometry of of the original polygon shapefile
                             res['geometry'] = mapping(shape(poly['geometry']))
                             output.write(res)
```

simple example
[image]

Answer (score 7):

See the PyQGIS Cookbook for advise how to add attributes to vector layers:
http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#adding-and-removing-fields

However the easier way in your situation would be to do a simple spatial join to add your point values to the polygons.